# Error when I boot

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04, via CD and USB.
When I put them on my laptop computer, It shows the following:

```
This Kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU : PAE
Unable to boot - Please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

My Laptop's specifications:
CPU : Intel Pentium M 725 1.6GHz
VGA : Geforce FX Go5200 64MB
RAM : 1GB DDR

It is an older machine.

My question is, why is this error appearing and how to I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CPU doesn't support PAE.

In computing, Physical Address Extension (PAE) is a feature to allow 32-bit x86 processors to access a physical address space (including random access memory and memory mapped devices) larger than 4 gigabytes. (wikipedia)

The easiest way to install ubuntu with unity is to download and burn the mini.iso, you can get 12.04 or one of the other mini.iso's here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Boot from it and follow the instructions, choose the latest linux-generic (without PAE) kernel (if you're asked to choose one, this depends on the choice you make how to install), and choose ubuntu-desktop when you are asked to select software to install. Do choose a desktop, if you don't you'll end up with a command-line system without a gui.

You might also consider to install Xubuntu or Lubuntu 12.10 because you are using an older laptop, Xubuntu or Lubuntu are more lightweight than Ubuntu and thus work faster. I recommend Lubuntu for speed.

Comment: Exactly what he said.

Comment: But when I boot another version of linux, Xubuntu, or like Backtrack5, monitor was cracked, then I couldn't longer proceed with the installation.

Comment: I don't know what "monitor was cracked" means, but it sounds like a nvidia-driver problem. Try out the mini.iso installation, if you choose lubuntu-desktop instead of ubuntu-desktop you'll get lubuntu. If it doesn't work ask another question and describe in detail what exactly happens.